# How to convert complicated JSON file structure to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, powerbi

This is what the JSON structure looks likes. I have taken out personal information from the data.

```
{
    "Version": "1.0",
    "IsUpToDate": false,
    "LastModificationGUID": "{numbers}",
    "DisplayName": "DATE",
    "CreateDate": "DATE AND TIME",
    "ServerID": 0,
    "CreatorServerID": 0,
    "TournamentID": "NUMBERS",
    "PitchMoundDistance": NUMBER,
    "SensorModel": 20,
    "Results": [
        {
            "Guid": "{NUMBERS}",
            "PitchServerID": 0,
            "HitServerID": 0,
            "PitchResult": {
                "LaunchSpeed": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "LaunchAzimDeg": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "LaunchElevDeg": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "BackspinRPM": -NUMBER,
                "SidespinRPM": -NUMBER,
                "RiflespinRPM": -NUMBER,
                "X": [
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER
                ],
                "Y": [
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER
                ],
                "Z": [
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                    LONG FLOATING NUMBER
                ],
                "FlightTime": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "TrackTime": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StartPositionX": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StartPositionY": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StartPositionZ": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneFrontPositionX": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneFrontPositionY": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneFrontPositionZ": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneFrontTime": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneBackPositionX": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneBackPositionY": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneBackPositionZ": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "StrikeZoneBackTime": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "BreakDistance": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MovementDistance": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "Extension": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBSpinAxisDeg": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBSpinTiltHoursOnly": 12,
                "MLBSpinTiltHours": 12,
                "MLBSpinTiltMinutes": 15,
                "MLBHBreak": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBVBreak": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBVBreakInduced": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBHMovement": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "MLBVMovement": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "SimpleHBreak": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "SimpleVBreak": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "SimpleHMovement": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "SimpleVMovement": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "PFX_X": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "PFX_Z": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "PX": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "PZ": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "X0": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "Y0": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "Z0": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "VX0": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "VY0": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "VZ0": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "AX": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "AY": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "AZ": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "ApproachSpeed": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "ApproachAzimDeg": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
                "ApproachElevDeg": -LONG FLOATING NUMBER
            },
            "Batter": "",
            "TriggerTime": "DATE WITH TIME",
            "PitchTypeShortCode": "FC",
            "PitchMechanicsShortCode": "ST",
            "PitchResultShortCode": "B",
            "PitchTypeDescription": "Cutter",
            "PitchMechanicsDescription": "Stretch",
            "PitchResultDescription": "Ball",
            "StrikeZoneTop": LONG FLOATING NUMBER,
            "StrikeZoneBottom": 0.5,
            "PitchStrikeZonePosition": 9,
            "PitcherName": "NAME",
            "PitcherID": "{NUMBERS AND LETTERS}",
            "PitcherIDType": "",
            "PitcherTeam": "NAME",
            "BatterName": "NAME",
            "BatterID": "{NUMBERS AND LETTERS}",
            "BatterIDType": "",
            "BatterTeam": "NAME",
            "PitchHandedness": "R",
            "SwingHandedness": "R",
            "HomeTeamBatting": false,
            "PAOfInning": 0,
            "PitchOfPA": 0
        },
        {
```

The structure continues like this after the comma. The most important part of the the structure is the Result attribute. I have tried flatting the file in Python, but it was not able to convert to data frame. I would like to convert it to CSV so I can make a visualization in PowerBI. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

JSON files and csv files serve different purposes. If your data is nested and you need to access specific layers in it - JSON/dictionary will be the way to go. If you are looking for a DataFrame type data structure - use csv.
I suggest you read more about both :)

edit: in the data you have written, I would use JSON

Comment: The best way to visualize JSON is using indents like you did above or tools like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ (if you need it in your code, there are open source projects that do that.). you can't visualize them like dataframes or csv data structures if that is your question.

Answer (score 0):

Converting JSON ist pretty easy. Once you load it into Python, the data becomes a dictionary. Those can be manipulated easily, e.g.:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print('The key is : '.format(key)
    print('The value is : '.format(value)
```

Etc. I'd suggest reading up on Python dictionaries, that should make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function to pretty print JSON files of arbitrary depth:

```
my_dict = {'a': {'b' : 'c', 'd': {'e': 'f'}}, 'g': 'h'}

def flatten_dict(some_dict, indent):
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        print('    ' * indent + 'Key : {}'.format(key))
        if type(value) == dict:
            indent += 1
            flatten_dict(value, indent)
        else:
            print('    ' * indent + 'Value : {}'.format(value))


flatten_dict(my_dict, 0)
```